# Connection refused when pulling docker image on windows server

Tags: docker, docker-machine, windows-server, windows-server-2022

After installing docker on a windows server i got the following error when pulling a image with docker run hello-world command:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://hub.docker.com/v2/: dial tcp
> 52.6.16.15:443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the proxy was blocking the request.

After some headaches, i finally got how to setup up proxy for docker on windows server from the right [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon#proxy-configuration):

Using powershell in elevated mode:

1. Set environment variable to `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("HTTP_PROXY", "http://username:password@proxy:port/", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

May not need to specify credentials, if your proxy don't require it.

2. Restart docker

```
 Restart-Service docker
```

Now it should run:

```
docker run hello-world
```